# If function returns text instead of number in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very simple formula, but it gives out unwanted result.

```
=IF(A1>=0,A1,0)
```

The above formula one gives 0 as **TEXT** if the if-statement is false for some reason. I did IsNumber() and it returns False. How can this be?

```
=IF(A1>0,0,A1)
```

This one gives 0 as a real number in a cell if the if-statement is true referencing the same exact cell A1.

```
A1 =IF(ISERROR(INDEX('$G$2:$G$80,MATCH($BQ$6,'$B$2:$B$80,0))), "0.000",INDEX('$G$2:$G$80,MATCH($BQ$6,'$B$2:$B$80,0)))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Care to share a small screenshot of cell `A1`? And tell us how it's formatted. As text? If `A1` is a numical value (not formatted as text or preceded by a `'`) then it should **not** return a string value.

Comment: The second formula also references to A1 and it returns a number. The formula for A1 is updated above. A1 is formatted as Number. The second formula works without an issue referencing it.

Comment: for me,its returning as number correctly. Can you change to the cell type to number manually and check ?

Comment: It won't change when I do it manually or paste format there. It's very strange, because the other formula works and this one doesn't. I can't fathom why.

Comment: Pasting format is not enough. You need to set format to General and recalculate the formula after that.

Comment: You will get the results you show (for the first two formulas) if A1 contains a `0` as text. Format of A1 is irrelevant.  And changing the format of A1 from text to number, or vice versa, will not change the data type of the value contained in A1.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not with cell A1 being formatted as text, since you have a formula in there calculating the result. The issue is with the formula in cell A1.

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$80,MATCH($BQ$6,$B$2:$B$80,0))), "0.000",INDEX($G$2:$G$80,MATCH($BQ$6,$B$2:$B$80,0)))
```

(This is after cleaning the remnant `'` characters, probably from where you removed references to another workbook)

In your formula, the `TRUE` return is `"0.000"`, since this is in quotes, this is interpreted as text not as a number. If you were to remove the quotes, the formula will auto-correct to `0` only, returning the actual numeric value 0.

If you want this to be formatted as 0.000, don't return `"0.000"` but return `0` and format your cell with a numeric format with 3 decimal places.

Comment: You got it. That solves the problem. I should not put "" in there, as it will put as text instead of number. Thanks a lot!